# Memory limit when uploading product image

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, error, memory

I just setup a testing installation yesterday. I ran the server-check file and all was fine. Installation went smoothly.

The image upload doesn't work in the Backend! After uploading any image, even as small as 1kb, the error "Memory limit has been reached." appears and the image is not stored.
The memory limit for PHP is set very high (several GiB or even -1 for unlimited)

Comment: the question is pretty clear... these mod's on this site are power tripping

Comment: I have the same problem and a solution! Since the power tripping mods closed it I can't answer!
Here is a short summary:
In the file `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`is the function ` _convertToByte` that doesn't know about GB or -1! add: `elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'G') !== false) {
                return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif (trim($memoryValue) == '-1') {
                return 8589934592;
        }`

Comment: hi josef.........

Comment: @Josef.  It was helped me , And thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to increase de memory limit of your php:

Open */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini* in a text editor

Change memory_limit to:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

And you can check creating a file *info.php*

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Check the variable: *memory limit*

Comment: Thanks!  I actually had the memory_limit set to -1 for unlimited so I didn't think that was the problem.  Reset it back to an actual limit and it's working fine.

Comment: @Tracy you can see my answer below to support unlimited memory limits.

Answer (score 9):

There is a known bug in the GD library of Magento CE 1.x where it can't handle memory limits other than in KB or MB. To solve the issue and assign higher memory limits (GB), you will need to make the following changes to the file `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`:

Find:

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
    if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
    }
 
    return (int)$memoryValue;
}
```

Add the following lines before the final `return` statement:

```
    elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'G') !== false) {    // Support value in gigabytes
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    elseif (trim($memoryValue) == '-1') {              // Support unlimited memory
        return 8589934592;                             // Use 8GB
    }
```

Thanks to Sangay Tenzin and [@Josef](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3616/josef) for making this info available.

Comment: Probably easier to just convert G to M, but nice to know about the BUG!

Comment: thanks.. its working for me. save my day.